# Template Literal Type checking Template Literals

Tags: typescript

I'm curious if the following is possible with the new Template Literal support in typescript 4.1:

```
export type LogDateType = `${number}.${number}.${number}` | `${number}.${number}` | `${number}`
```

I've found this works if I'm type checking a string like `2002` or `2002.5.12` but fails when type checking something like:

```
`${fourDigitYear}`
```

with the error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'LogDateType'.`

Is there a way to have this work outside of checking plain strings?

Answer (score 0):

Issues: [#41732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41732) and [#41631](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41631)

assert it as `const`

```
export type LogDateType = `${number}.${number}.${number}` | `${number}.${number}` | `${number}`

const fourDigitYear = "2000";

const foo: LogDateType = `${fourDigitYear}` as const;
```