# Typescript Template Literal Type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Has anyone ever ran Typescript template literal not being able to recognize the type if it's constructed using a variable before?

Here's the code snippet:

```
const namespace = 'myNamespace';

type Keys = 'a' | 'b';

type NamespacedKeys = `${typeof namespace}/${Keys}`;

type NamespacedObjects = Record<NamespacedKeys, string>;

const foo: NamespacedObjects = {
  [`${namespace}/a`]: 'bar',
  [`${namespace}/b`]: 'toto',
} // this would have an error -> Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties

const baz: NamespacedObjects = {
  'myNamespace/a': 'bar',
  'myNamespace/b': 'yolo',
} // this works
```

Comment: change `keys` to `Keys` in your example, please

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Template Literal Type checking Template Literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66464355/template-literal-type-checking-template-literals/66464661#66464661)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler does not automatically infer a [template literal *type*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) when it encounters a [template literal *expression*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).  For example:

```
const key = `${namespace}/a`; 
// const key: string
```

The inferred type of `key` is just `string` and not a string literal.  If you want the compiler to infer a string literal type for that, you need to explicitly ask it to do so with a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const key2 = `${namespace}/a` as const; 
// const key2: "myNamespace/a"
```

Wondering why this doesn't happen automatically?  Well, there was work done in [microsoft/TypeScript#41891](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/41891) to do this... and it apparently broke a bunch of real world code that was already using template literal expressions but depending on its type being just `string` and not some string literal.  So this was reverted in [microsoft/TypeScript#42588](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42588).  For now we will just have to use a `const` assertion, at least until the TS team figures out how to get better behavior without breaking too much existing code:

```
const foo: NamespacedObjects = {
  [`${namespace}/a` as const]: 'bar',
  [`${namespace}/b` as const]: 'toto',
} // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCGBbAphADvYyYF4YHJEBPAOSVQy3wG4BYAKAaiLWwGlkiJcD58YAPgQBGNBkxbYyKdJmQATDlx4ADACQBvZqxAAzOOVlYAvgHpNSiMZV1G9bVMOUFAeWEArZMCjc8AJS8QACd5AB5pCjlFTggAGhhoIIBLMABzAD5bBlBIWABrTlVNBBlnM3gbBlNTGBzoGAKiAC4EqGS08Xo6-M4AJiKNEsiTUwqYeG5u22ra8HrG3paAImIIo2RRpc7umF0QEBa153k3T29fGA0GGBgAbXVBpzlylXHJuagAXRb8YXgg-Cxa53B5DdZmYSvCazXLfAhQEAIwEMYwwGYgPLwIidIA)